# What is the difference among 'estante' vs 'repisa' vs 'balda'?

Tags: sustantivos, sinónimos, diferencias-entre-palabras

Is there any difference in meaning between "estante", "repisa" and "balda", when they mean "shelf" (an horizontal surface on which you put objects) ?

I had never heard "balda" before, but I have just heard it in the TV series "Vis a Vis", which takes place in Spain. Is that word used exclusively in that country?

Comment: It should be noted that repisa has several related meanings: https://dle.rae.es/repisa?m=form (estante has even more meanings but they are unrelated). I would say repisa is often used for other kind of shelf-like surfaces - like an elongated niche in some old houses that can be used as a shelf. The use of "repisa rocosa" (a geological or topographical feature) is a natural extension of the meaning of repisa that wouldn't work with estante.

Answer (score 7):

According to the DRAE:

> [estante](https://dle.rae.es/estante)
> 5. m. Cada una de las tablas **dispuestas horizontalmente** en un mueble o **en la pared** para colocar objetos sobre ellas.
>
> [repisa](https://dle.rae.es/repisa)
> 2. f. **Estante** o placa de madera, cristal u otro material, **colocados horizontalmente contra la pared** para servir de soporte a algo.
>
> [balda](https://dle.rae.es/balda)
> **estante**

As you have pointed everyone of them matches the definition of **[shelf](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shelf)** provided by the Oxford Dictionary

> **A flat length of wood** or rigid material, **attached to a wall** or forming part of a piece of furniture, that provides a surface for the storage or display of objects.

But notice that the definition of **repisa** doesn't mention it as part of a piece of furniture. It usually refers to a shelf directly attached to the wall, la pared. I've never heard that word mentioned as part of a bookshelf (estantería). I tend to identify a repisa also for being made of something different from wood like plaster (escayola) or stone (piedra) but I can't not generalize such distinction to all Spanish speakers.

I'm from Spain so I can not answer the second part of your question. **Balda** is a common word here, there's nothing strange about it being mentioned in a TV series.

Comment: Balda is not used in Argentina, or at least I've never heard it.

Comment: Could Mexicans and Colombians confirm that "balda" is not usual in their countries either? I suspect this word is not used in Latin America.